# Paginate Tree Array

Tags: php, arrays, pagination

I am looking at trying to build pagination method for an array. I have an array something like below. Before you suggest making the pagination work for sql query, I have already done so and it did work for a flat array but a requirement is having this multidimensional tree array.

```
array = (
   item_id = 5,
   parent_id = 0,
   children = array(
      array(
         item_id = 20,
         parent_id = 5,
         children = array(
            array(
               item_id = 24,
               parent_id = 20
            ),
            array(
               item_id = 24,
               parent_id = 20
            )
         )
      )
   )
);
```

What methods that I can find don't seem to work with such an array since array_slice will only work on the first level of the array and doesn't take into consideration the children levels.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
$root = 
[
    'id' => 1,
    'children' => [...]
]

$queue[] = $root
$visiteds[] = $root
while ($queue){
    $current = array_shift($queue);
    // do whatever with the current ex: echo $current."<br>"
    if $current has children {
        foreach child {             
            if ($child NOT in $visiteds) { // $child not visited before
                $visiteds[] = $child // mark as visited                 
                $queue[] = $child // add to queue
                // do whatever with the child ex: echo $child ."<br>"
            }
        }
    }
}
*/
```

Note: if you want to visit exactly same children as required (for example 2 exactly same child must be visited twice then, remove `$visiteds` related parts. *In this case be careful that your graph structure must not have cycling*.)

You may consider to read about Graph Theory, Breadth First Search algorithm, Depth First Search algorithm.